# How can I find a "powershell-script" in windows?

Tags: windows, shell, powershell

Someone has added a custom command to my windows git shell. When I write build ... It runs powershell inside gitshell and executes a build on the server. I'm trying to get this script running from Shell turtlestein in sublime text.

To get started I need to find the script that is running. I assume it's similair to a bash-script in unix. I need to find it somehow, for example: Are they stored in some location or can I find the reference somewhere? Do they have a specific fileending?

Comment: Have you tried looking for a directory named "git-shell-commands"?
According to http://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell.html it should be in your home directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like this command is contained in a module. If your running Powershell v4 then it will be in c:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules, if not check c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\1.0\Modules.